# How do I make my stored variables accessible to all classes? (UWP Windows.Storage, C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I am using ApplicationData.LocalSettings to save my variables between forms and for when the user closes and reopens the application. When I try to read the saved variables in another form, I need to insert the code into a method to use `localSettings.Values`; otherwise, I get the error "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property FormName.localSettings":

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

    Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue composite =
       (Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue)localSettings.Values["nutritionSettings"]; //this line brings the error
```

When I insert these lines of code into a method, it works, like this:

```
static void Storage()
    {
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue composite =
           (Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue)localSettings.Values["nutritionSettings"];
    }
```

However, I have not been able to figure out how to make the saved variables accessible outside of this method.  Whenever I try to access them, I get the error, "The name 'composite' does not exist in this context':

```
 public LogFood()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();


        int calorieMin = Convert.ToInt32(composite["calorieMin"]);
        int calorieMax = Convert.ToInt32(composite["calorieMax"]);
        int gramsFatMin = Convert.ToInt32(composite["gramsFatMin"]);
        int gramsFatMax = Convert.ToInt32(composite["gramsFatMax"]);
        int gramsCarbsMin = Convert.ToInt32(composite["gramsCarbsMin"]);
        int gramsCarbsMax = Convert.ToInt32(composite["gramsCarbsMax"]);
        int gramsProteinMin = Convert.ToInt32(composite["gramsProteinMin"]);
        int gramsProteinMax = Convert.ToInt32(composite["gramsProteinMax"]);

    }
```

What should I change about the method so that I can access these variables anywhere in the code for this form? I'm a bit new to C# as a whole, and methods as a whole tend to confuse me. Any recommended reading or documentation would be helpful.

Comment: You need to declare `composite` as `public static` at the class level, not as a simple local variable.

Comment: Okay. What data type is    composite    in this case?

Comment: It’s right there in your code.

Answer (score 0):

> "The name 'composite' does not exist in this context'

The problem is that you did not declare `composite` object in `LogFood` class.
If you want to make variables accessible to all classes. You could declare public static in `App` class and John Wu is correct. For more please refer the following steps.

```
public static ApplicationDataCompositeValue composite;
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    composite = (Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue)localSettings.Values["nutritionSettings"];
}
```

**Usage**

```
public LogFood()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    int calorieMin = Convert.ToInt32(App.composite["calorieMin"]);
}
```